# Provide path of the file to be downloaded in django

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, imagedownload

views.py

```js
def download(request, path):
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/pdf")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
            return response
    raise Http404
```

urls.py

```js
from unicodedata import name
from django.urls import path
from Profile import views

urlpatterns = [
  ...
  path('download/<str:path>/', views.download, name="download"),
]
```

models.py

```js
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

# Create your models here.
class ProfileModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255 , null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

template

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
Welcome, {{request.user.username}}
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name: </th>
        <th>{{user.first_name}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Last Name: </th>
        <th>{{user.last_name}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Email: </th>
        <th>{{user.email}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Image: </th>
        {% if user.image %}
        <!-- here is the error -->
        <th><a href="{% url 'download' user.image.url%}"><img src=" {{user.image.url}}" alt="IMage...." style="object-fit: cover;
            border-radius: 50%;
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;"></a></th>
        {% endif %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Address: </th>
        <th>{{user.address}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Bio: </th>
        <th>{{user.bio|linebreaks}}</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')

The problem is with the path I have provided for the file to be downloaded in the template. I don't know the correct way to give the required path of the file to the download view.
Error - "Reverse for 'download' with arguments '('/images/Nitro_Wallpaper_5000x2813_Vm2jvWw.jpg',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['Profile/download/(?P[^/]+)/\Z']".
But "Nitro_Wallpaper_5000x2813_Vm2jvWw.jpg" is present in my images folder.

Comment: Your pattern is `'download/<str:path>/'`  while your try to specify path as `'/images/Nitro_Wallpaper_5000x2813_Vm2jvWw.jpg'`, the `str` url converter specifically does **not** accept slashes. Although all of that can be said to be irrelevant since it seems you just want to create links to media files? Read the documentation on [How to manage static files (e.g. images, JavaScript, CSS)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/), also see [How to deploy static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/deployment/) for production.

Comment: I just need the correcct file path. I know about sattic files already. If you know the answer then tell

Comment: I could post an answer (I consider that to be reinventing the wheel though) but what stops you from simply writing `urlpatterns = [ ... ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` as the documentation states? Note that serving media files using Django itself is inefficient.

Comment: I already have urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT).

Comment: Working successfully now after some changes.

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```js
def download(request, filename):
    path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, filename)
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, path)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/octet-stream")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
            return response
    raise Http404
```

template

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
Welcome, {{request.user.username}}
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name: </th>
        <th>{{user.first_name}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Last Name: </th>
        <th>{{user.last_name}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Email: </th>
        <th>{{user.email}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Image: </th>
        {% if user.image %}
        <th><a href="{% url 'download' user.image%}"><img src="{{user.image.url}}" alt="IMage...." style="object-fit: cover;
            border-radius: 50%;
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;"></a></th>
        {% endif %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Address: </th>
        <th>{{user.address}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Bio: </th>
        <th>{{user.bio|linebreaks}}</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Providing just the file name in the function parameter and set the filepath in the download view. Also set the content_type as octet/stream.